# inet_ntoa returns a pointer, but where does it point to, stack or heap?

Tags: network-programming

inet_ntoa() returns a character pointer, but I'm at a loss where it points to, stack or heap?

```
char* func(unsigned int n){
    char *p = inet_ntoa(n);
    return p;
}
```

what is the lifetime and scope of the character string pointed by p?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It points to a statically allocated buffer, it's lifetime is until the end of the application (or thread).

You can think of inet_ntoa as being roughly:

```
static char buffer[BIG_ENOUGH]
char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in)
(
    //perform conversion to ascii into "buffer"
    return buffer;
}
```

So note that inet_ntoa() is not reentrant. This means it reuses the same buffer, so with this code:

```
char *p1 = inet_ntoa(a);
char *p2 = inet_ntoa(b);
```

`p1` and `p2` will point to the same buffer, and both have the IP address of the most recent call to `inet_ntoa()`. It also means you cannot call `inet_ntoa()` from several threads without providing your own locking. (1)

(1) - some implementation use a thread local variable for the buffer it returns, in which case inet_ntoa() is thread safe, but still not re-entrant. In such a case the lifetime of the returned pointer will also be until the thread ends, not until the entire application ends.